# How to convert a video into m4v format in python without saving to a file

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I would like to convert videos into m4v format in python without saving video to a file.
I tried ffmpeg - `ffmpeg -i v1.mp4 v1.m4v` . It works great but it needs to store the output to a file.
My code runs on google app engine where storing files is not advised.

`ffmpeg-python` also requires the output to be streamed to a file.

Is there a way to build a python function `f1(input_video)` which would return output_video in m4v format.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4V

m4v is a file format, there is no reason to care about a file format if you don't want a file.

If the code is for an online app, then maybe you need to make a way so that python creates the file, and then deletes it again after short time, so that it is possible to download the file.m4v before it is deleted.